# Почему не удаётся использовать полосу прокрутки в ListView?

Tags: wpf

Она отображается, но ею нельзя пользоваться . Из-за чего это может быть ?

```
  <StackPanel Margin="10 0 10 0">

            <ScrollViewer IsEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

                <ListView  x:Name="listBook"   BorderThickness="0"
                  
                 Background="Transparent">
                 
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                       <Border 
                            Canvas.Top="30"
                            Width="100"                                
                            Margin="0 5 0 5"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"       
                            BorderBrush="Blue"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="10">
                                
                           <Border.Effect>
                              <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20"
                                  Opacity=".5"
                                  ShadowDepth="1" />
                           </Border.Effect>

                           <Border Name="ReceiverColor"
                                   BorderBrush="#FF96B2E4"
                                   BorderThickness="2"
                                   CornerRadius="10">
                               <Grid>
                                    <Border Name="Mask"
                                            Background="White"
                                            BorderBrush="#FF3B5998"
                                            BorderThickness="0"
                                            CornerRadius="10">
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Margin="5">
                                             <Image.Source>
                                                 <Binding Path="Book.Image">
                                                     <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                                                         <ImageSource>
                                                             /Resources/imageNull.png
                                                         </ImageSource>

                                                     </Binding.TargetNullValue>

                                                 </Binding>
                                             </Image.Source>
                                        </Image>
                                         <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                              <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}" />
                                         </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                                    </StackPanel>
                               </Grid>
                           </Border>
                      </Border>


                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book.NameBook}" Margin="110 9 0 0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="Автор книги:"  Margin="110 45 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Book.AuthorOfThebook}"  Margin="205 45 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal"/>


                        <TextBlock Text="Год издания:"  Margin="110 65 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Book.YearOfPublication, StringFormat=MM.dd.yyyy}"  Margin="205 65 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal"/>




                            <TextBlock Text="Книга выдана:" 
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Margin="0 0 180 5"/>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="0 0 128 5" FontSize="14"
                            Text="{Binding SchoolBoy.SurName}"/>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="0 0 60 5" FontSize="14"
                            Text="{Binding SchoolBoy.Name}"/>


                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            Margin="0 0 30 5" FontSize="14"
                            Text="{Binding Class.Number}"/>

                   </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

            </ScrollViewer >
        </StackPanel>
```

Стиль ListView

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
   
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border CornerRadius="20" x:Name="Bd"
                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        
                        BorderBrush="#1E90FF"                                                                                
                        BorderThickness="1" Background="White"
                        Padding="10 0 0 0" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                      
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                                     
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#E6E6FA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#4169E1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                   
                   
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A0522D"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF8DC"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: На сколько я помню, `StackPanel` ровняет элементы по конкретному краю (верх или левый), а не растягивает их на всю длину/ширину, из-за чего и скрол там не будет работать, ибо нет четких размеров объекта. Хотите "четкости", задавайте размеры объектам, тем самым фиксируя их (что бредово), либо берите сетку или чет подобное.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Грустно конечно что StackPanel не поддерживает скрол :(

Answer (score 0):

Всё, поправил косяк обернул StackPanel в   `<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">`

ну и закрывающий тег в конце

Касаемо прокрутки = (если не наведена мышка на скролл, то вот код)

в xmal создаём событие `PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel"`

```
ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta / 3);
        e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).